# How can I fix my code to allow a user to select up to 4 dates on the calendar?

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/kz7d2/ link to fiddle.

I want a user to be allowed to select 4 dates consecutively or not does matter.

```
    var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("somedate")[0].setAttribute('min', today);


<input name="somedate" type="date">
```

Comment: Is there some reason just having four inputs wouldn't suffice?

Comment: yeah that is what I ended up doing actually

Answer (score 0):

You can use datepick.js.

Here is link for demo: [Link](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML)

select multiple dates using :

```js
$('#multi999Picker').datepick({ 
    multiSelect: 999, monthsToShow: 2, 
    showTrigger: '#calImg'});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="multi999Picker" size="60" class="is-datepick">
```

Comment: that isn't working for me can you please explain more

Comment: datepicker.js is plugin did you install it in project ?

Comment: 1. Include the jQuery library in the head section of your page.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and $(selector).datepick();

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to add two large dependencies. jQuery is 86k minified, datepicker.js is another 35.6k. That adds 121kB of JavaScript that must be parsed and executed, just to allow selection of multiple dates.